# Vue autocomplete with axios call in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, autocomplete

I feel like I'm really close to getting this Vue autocomplete with axios working but I'm still missing a key component.

I've tested this with hard-coded test data, but I need to figure out how to get my axios call to properly query my controller. The route currently set in the axios call hits the function in my controller below, but I need to know what to set my `$query` variable to so that It triggers the database call with the actual values the user is typing.

How can I properly send the request through axios and return the data to my `this.options` in axios?

Blade:

```
<div id="tagApp">
  <multiselect
    v-model="value"
    :options="options"
    :loading="loading"
    :multiple="true"
    :taggable="true"
    @search-change="val => read(val)"
  ></multiselect>
</div>


new Vue({
      components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
      },
      el: "#tagApp",
      data: {
        value: [],
        loading: false,
        options: [],

      },
      methods: {
        read: function(val){
            console.log('searched for', val);
          if (val) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.options = [];

            const self = this;

            axios.get('campaigns/search',{params: {query: this.val}})
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.options = response.data;
            });

          } else {
            this.options = [];
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

Controller:

```
public function searchTags(Request $request)
{

    $query = $request->get('query);

    $data = CampaignTags::where('TAG_DATA', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

    return json_encode($data);


}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @AkenRoberts at this point just a matter of tying my results to the options of my multiselect. I can console log the results to see the autocomplete working but I can't figure out how to append them to options

Comment: @AkenRoberts so if I console.log response.data then I see the results I want but I need to tie them to the options

Comment: @AkenRoberts do you happen to see any issues in my JS that are causing the data to not be tied into the options?

Comment: Try changing `const self = this` to `let self = this`. Constants are not meant to be changed, and it could be where it's stalling. Beyond that, without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I would just check the Vue Multiselect [documentation](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-asynchronous-select) to be sure you've set things up correctly.